# Google App Engine: How to render template via AJAX POST request?

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm developing a web-app with Google App Engine Python SDK.

I'm unable to render a new HTML page server-side from an AJAX request.

Specifically, I have an input field with AJAX request event attached to it. The URL routes to a class in my python code, and I render a new Jinja template in it.

Any idea why this would not work? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Sorry, but to get some help you have to show us the code. Please keep it to the minimum required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying? Don't you just need to redirect your page? I mean, if your solely using Jinja2 templates.